# Can we POST JWT token in thymeleaf form

Tags: spring, post, jwt, thymeleaf

```
<form th:action="@{add}" th:object="${student}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label> <input th:field="*{email}" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First name</label> <input th:field="*{firstName}" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can we include requestHeader which has JWT token, while making a POST call using spring and thymleaf?

Answer (score 5):

You can't, you have to write some javascript to make the post request instead of the form posting. In your javascript ajax call, you can specify the custom header. In your case: the Authentication header which has the JWT in it.